# Electrolysis of Potassium Iodate/Hydrogen Peroxide in Briggs-Rauscher Oscillation

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox, electrolysis

I would like to investigate the effect of adding a voltage in the Briggs-Rauscher oscillation reaction. I will examine the oscillations visually.

The ingredients I will use include potassium iodate, sulfuric acid, acetone, manganese sulfate, starch indicator and hydrogen peroxide.

There are a number of complex reactions which have not to this day been completely analysed. Hence I will not attempt to explain all of them.

To the point. **What electrodes should I use for electrolysing potassium iodate? Just like the saltwater circuit, would electrolysis will proceed as iodine carries charges towards the aluminium anode, and as potassium obtains them in the copper cathode? Could I electrolyse hydrogen peroxide alternatively?**

I would like to examine reduction potentials, comparing them to what extent the electrolysis of potassium iodide prevents the behavior of potassium iodide in the other equilibria, as possibly seen visually.

Is it also possible for the manganese metal to conduct with copper just as potassium might?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experiment has been attempted. Electrolysis through the use of copper electrodes in fact "kills" the reaction. This means that the whole system is immediately turned dark-blue, and eventually made more clearer, and eventually light blue indicating the presence of copper ions.

It is suspected that not only is the sulphate ion electrolysed, but perhaps the copper iodizes the potassium and other compounds.